# Angular returning array values wrapped in []

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am working on teaching myself Angular at the moment, and I am currently getting to grips with sending http requests from my angular front-end.

I am successfully sending a POST request, and I am also getting the correct error response back. The error response returned is from Laravel and basically a JSON response.

```
return Response::json(['message' => $validator->errors()], 422);
```

This returns something that looks like,

```
   {
       "message": {
           "first_name": ["The first name field is required."],
           "surname": ["The surname field is required."],
           "email": ["The email field is required."],
           "school_name": ["The school name field is required."]
       }
   }
```

In my angular template I have this in my controller for now,

```
app.controller('signupController', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("...signup controller initialised...");
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.error = "";
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        console.log($scope.formData);
        var postForm = $http.post('http://homestead.app/api/invites/create', $scope.formData);
        postForm.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;
        });
        postForm.error(function(data, status, headers) {
            $scope.error = data;
            console.log($scope.error);
        });
    }
});
```

In my template I form entries that looks like this,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName" class="is-required">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="first_name" ng-model="formData.firstname" ng-class="{'has-error': error.message.first_name}">
    <div class="error__block">{{ error.message.first_name }}</div>
</div>
```

Now on error the form input get the has-error class assigned, but the error block shows something like this,

> ["The first name field is required."]

When I would have thought it would show something like this,

> The first name field is required

Am I doing something incorrectly on my laravel end of my angular end?

Comment: If your function returns an array, that's how arrays get encoded in JSON. If you want just the string, maybe reference it with `[0]` to take the first element? Be aware this design might be intentional to accommodate multiple errors.

Comment: I am being so stupid (long day at work). My form inputs can have multiple validations errors returned with hence the arrays!

Answer (score 2):

from what I see you're returning from laravel an array of string values for the field **first_name** . That doesn't really sound okay, shouldn't it be simply a string?

If not, **[join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)** the first_name array and you'll get the whole name from multiple values in array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Laravel so there may still be a way to change that, but you can make a change in your `$http.success()` function like this:

```
postForm.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data[0];
});
```

Instead of setting `$scope.message` to the incoming array, it will grab the first element of the array and use that instead (index 0).